# Correct notation when proving that $\hat{\beta_1}$ is linear

Tags: self-study, least-squares, linear-model, assumptions

When reviewing lecture slides for the proof that $\hat{\beta_1}$ is linear in OLS-regression my teacher posted the following on the lecture slides:
$$\hat{\beta_1}=\frac{\sum(X_i-\bar{X})Y_i}{\sum(X_i-\bar{X})^2}= \sum a_iY_i  \text{   where   }a_i= \frac{(X_i-\bar{X})}{\sum(X_i-\bar{X})^2}$$

But when I look at the same proof in the textbook the teacher referenced for a further discussion of this proof (*Introduction to Econometrics* by Stock&Watson, appendix 5.2) the same proof have the following notation: $\hat{a_i}= \frac{(X_i-\bar{X})}{(X_i-\bar{X})^2}$ . Note that there is no $\sum$-sign in the denomination in the second case.

**So my questions are:**

1. Which is the correct notation?
2. If the correct notation is $\frac{(X_i-\bar{X})}{\sum(X_i-\bar{X})^2}$, I would be grateful for an explanation of why this is the case since $\frac{(X_i-\bar{X})}{(X_i-\bar{X})^2}$ intuitively feels correct.

Comment: neither notation makes sense, since the index $i$ is never defined and not used to index X. Better notation is $a_i = \frac{X_{1,i} - \bar{X}_1}{\sum_{j} (X_{1,j} - \bar{X}_1)^2}$, then $\hat{\beta}_1 = \sum_{i} a_i Y_i$ again.

Comment: The correct formulas are with 1 replaced by i. @JohnMadden, I guess this is simple regression, thus the double index is redundant.

Comment: @utobi ah that mostly makes sense.... but then why does $\hat{\beta}$ have that 1 subscript? haha maybe we're reading too far into this

Comment: @JohnMadden to read even further, maybe the parameters are called beta0 and beta1…

Comment: @JohnMadden the subscript is of course supposed to be $X_i$ not $X_1$. I've edited the original question.

Comment: @JohnMadden Why did you ad the j-subscript in the denominator?

Comment: @AoMRos just to make clear that there's one sum in the denominator, and a different one in the numerator. Or in other words, to make clear that it's different than the index $i$ which subscripts $a_i$.

Comment: @JohnMadden Which sum in the numerator do you mean? In your first comment you did not put a sum in the numerator?

Comment: @utobi Done (If you can't tell I'm new here haha)

Comment: @AoMRos the sum in the numerator of your very first equation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming we are talking about the simple linear regression model

$$
Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i + \epsilon_i,\quad i=1,\ldots,n,
$$
with $\epsilon_i\sim N(0,\,\sigma^2)$, $\sigma^2>0$, independently and identically. Doing the calculations yourself will notice that the OLS estimator for $\beta_1$ is

\begin{align*}
\hat \beta_1 &= \frac{\sum_i (Y_i-\bar Y)(X_i-\bar X)}{\sum_i(X_i-\bar X)^2} = \frac{\sum_i Y_i(X_i-\bar X)-\sum_i \bar Y(X_i-\bar X)}{\sum_i(X_i-\bar X)^2}\tag{*}\\ 
&= \sum_i a_iY_i.\tag{**}
\end{align*}

The first equality in (*) is just OLS, the second equality is algebra and equality in (**) is due to a certain property of the average. I'm leaving the rest of the details to you since this is a `self-study` question.

Comment: You assume correct. 
On the right hand side of = in $(*)$ , shouldn't the sum that is subtracted in the numerator be $\sum_i\bar{Y}(X_i-\bar{X})$?

Comment: I've managed to simplify the euation above as far as $\frac{\sum(X_i-\bar{X})}{\sum(X_i-\bar{X})^2} * Y_i=\hat{\beta_1}$  and $a_i$ would thus equal $\frac{\sum(X_i-\bar{X})}{\sum(X_i-\bar{X})^2}$. The problem is that this is different than both the fractions I included in my original question and despite my very best efforts i have not been able to get any further.

Comment: I've slept on this now and I think I got it!

If $\frac{\sum(X_i-\bar{X})}{\sum(X_i-\bar{X})^2}*Y_i=\sum a_i Y_i=\hat{\beta_1}$ then $a_i=\frac{(X_i-\bar{X})}{(X_i-\bar{X})^2}$. 
Is this correct?

Comment: Thank you so much. This was driving me asolutely crazy